# Generic getDefaultInstance() for java protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I'm trying to write a static util function that takes in a protobuf object and determine if it's a default instance, something along the line of:

```java
static boolean isDefault(ProtobufMessage m) {
  return m.equals(m.getDefaultInstance())
}
```

Would like for it to be able to apply to a range of protobuf objects like Struct / Types / Messages, however `getDefaultInstance()` appears to only get defined in the child classes.

I'm thinking along the lines of polymorphism or generics but unsure if it can be applied in this case, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late to this question, but you could make use of `getDefaultInstanceForType()`, which comes from the `MessageLiteOrBuilder` class and isn't static:

```
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import java.util.Objects;

static boolean isDefault(Message m) {
  return Objects.equals(m.getDefaultInstanceForType(), m);
}
```

Here is the method in the docs: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLiteOrBuilder.html#getDefaultInstanceForType--